# macOS - The Gods are punishing me. The app's receipt fails miserably to load, no matter what I do

Tags: macos, cocoa, app-store, storekit, receipt-validation

I have tested all solutions on similar questions on SO and they all failed for me.

I think mine is different because the application's receipt is not even loading.

I am having developing this macOS app for at least 7 months. The app contains Auto-Renewable Subscription.

Since day one, I am retrieving and validating its receipt with success. No problem at all. That were the good days.

January 3, 2020, I started working on the app again.

Since then, the app fails miserably to even load the receipt. No change in code, nothing.

Even a simple code like this, that is copied from Apple, fails.

```
// Get the receipt if it's available
if let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL,
    FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path) {

    do {
        let receiptData = try Data(contentsOf: appStoreReceiptURL, options: .alwaysMapped)
        print(receiptData)

        let receiptString = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])

        // Read receiptData
    }
    catch { print("Couldn't read receipt data with error: " + error.localizedDescription) }
} else {      
  exit(173)
  print("this error stinks!")
}
```

this line

```
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path)
```

fails miserably. The receipt is not there.

This is what I have tried so far:

1. cry
2. restart the computer
3. delete `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore`
4. create a new sandbox user
5. try with an old sandbox user created years ago.
6. reinstall Xcode
7. log out of App Store and iCloud + restart the computer again.
8. killed the storeaccountd daemon + restart.
9. confirmed that the version and the bundleID on Info.plist are the same as in appstoreConnect.

Everything I get is

> networkError(error: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)")

`exit(173)` is triggered, I type the sandbox user then I get

> The app is damaged and can’t be opened. Delete the app and download it again from the App Store.

I have had this problem on an iOS device application I was developing 10 years ago and the only way I have managed to solve that was by resetting the device to factory default. Sincerely, I will not reinstall macOS.

I am desperate. I have aged 20 years in the last couple of days.

Is there some cache or macOS service that might be clogged?

One thing I have noticed is that the box the pops to type the App Store credentials do not show the words `sandbox` as the boxes the pop when you try to buy the in-app purchase and that this boxes always comes pre-filled with an old sandbox user. Is there a way to clean that?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opened a technical incident with Apple and they were unable to solve that.

Someone suggested me the only thing that solved the problem: to create another user on the same Mac and test it from there.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

If you are having this problem from iOS, the solution is to reset the device to factory defaults.

---

Note: apparently, this time, the whole problem was caused by Apple, after a [half cooked update](https://twitter.com/RevenueCat/status/1220024020654907392?s=20) to their sandbox/production servers.